# Constant memory dumps

Tags: memory, dump

Is it possible to constantly dump the memory of a process to record every change that is happening? For example if I have a program that modifies the contents of an array I'd like to know the contents of that array before some modification. I imagine a program could save the initial memory and then all changes in a file and I'd just search the file by the modified contents of the array which I know. Then I'd look for changes in that specific memory location before that moment and find the initial contents.
Does a program like that exist? If so, what program would you recommend?

EDIT: I wrote a program in C++ that captures packets of another process using pcap and I would like to know how these packets are constructed inside that program. I'm using Windows.

Comment: Please explain what concrete application you have in mind.

Comment: sounds like you need an "action replay". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Replay

Answer (score 0):

Notice that memory content is (or may be) changing a lot faster than what a disk is capable of writing.

Also, your question is OS specific. I guess that you are using Linux.

In all cases, design your application very early with your goals.

Perhaps you are looking for [application checkpointing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing). If on Linux, consider [BLCR](http://crd.lbl.gov/departments/computer-science/CLaSS/research/BLCR/).

Perhaps you are looking for some [persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_%28computer_science%29) mechanism. A possible way might be to explicitly persist the state of your application at some points in your program, which are executed frequently. Persistence of the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) or of [continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation)  is a difficult issue

You may want to use textual formats (like [JSON](http://json.org/)) for [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). You could be interested in database technology, either relational-SQL (e.g. [Sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) or [PostGreSQL](http://postgresql.org/)) or noSQL [mongodb](http://mongodb.org/)

Persistence and checkpointing may be related to [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) algorithms (notably copying GC).

Some language implementations are able to persist their entire heap. For example, in [Common Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp), the [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) implementation offers [save-lisp-and-die](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Saving-a-Core-Image)

For debugging, you might want [watchpoints](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html), or the [gcore(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcore.1.html) command.

Notice that if you [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) your process and sleep or idle immediately the child process you are keeping in that child process a snapshot of your address space.

Read also about [transactional memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_memory) & [ACID properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)